# How to create consumer Rabbitmq dynamically?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to launch RabbitMQ consumer dynamically. A mean connect consumer to exist queue after specific time?

Or all consumers should be created in advance?

My case can be without consumers, when queues are filled by messages. Could I connect consumers after some time?

Comment: Plese take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html to get an understanding of the basic AMQP concepts.

Comment: Thank you, I have read, but I dont understand whats is consumer, is it server script or it is client (JS)?

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do it just like channel not yet created.
example for node.js

```
const conn = await amqplib.connect(`${rabbitmq.url}?heartbeat=300`);
conn.on('error', function (err) {
    api.log.error('AMQP:Error:', err);
});
conn.on('close', () => {
    api.log.info("AMQP:Closed");
});

const ch = await conn.createChannel();
await ch.assertQueue(queue_name, queue_options); // check if queue_name exists,
                                                 // if not, creates it
await ch.consume(queue_name, callback) // message from queue goes to callback
```

Comment: Спасибо, Егор! So, could I also stop consumer if client is offline?

Comment: @OPV The cosumer *is* the client. Note that a consumer is *not* created by the RabbitMQ server but by a client.

Comment: Only if you know from some other sources that there is no consumer